# Dumping, then loading a sqlite3 DB for WagTail

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to copy the contents of a production DB to then use for local development. I've tried using sqlite's dump and then doing `cat dump.sql | sqlite3 db.sqlite3`, but this just prints out loads of errors like:

```
Error: near line 3: table "django_migrations" already exists
Error: near line 4: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_migrations.id
Error: near line 5: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_migrations.id
Error: near line 6: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_migrations.id
Error: near line 7: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_migrations.id
Error: near line 8: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_migrations.id
Error: near line 9: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_migrations.id
```

I've also tried using Django's own dump/load commands, but when I do`./manage.py loaddata db.json` I get loads of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jack/dev/web_design/kaoru_wada/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jack/dev/web_design/kaoru_wada/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_content_type.app_label, django_content_type.model
```

I get these errors even if I delete the existing local DB, run migrations, and then try and import the dbdumps into the fresh local DB.

Any ideas on how to copy the DB contents and successfully import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .sql dump file contains the information for constructing database tables as well as the data to populate them, so there's no need to run migrations as a separate step - that will just duplicate part of the process (and throw errors as it tries to create tables that already exist).

Simply running the `cat dump.sql | sqlite3 db.sqlite3` step without creating the `db.sqlite3` file beforehand will give you a fully populated database in the same state as if you'd run migrations.